# Is it important to have same firebase account with a Google Playstore account?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, admob

I have not yet had a playstore account. I have an app associated with FlashBase. However, I want to open a play store account with another google account. Is this possible?
Is it important to have a firebase account with a Google Playstore account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Firebase` account has nothing to do with your `Playstore` account. While `PlayStore` account is limited to you device, your `FirebaseAccount` is used to manage your app's database and analytics.

PlayStore account will help you

- to download apps, games, movies, books etc
- will help you to sync across multiple devices.

With Firebase which is usually for Developers,

- you can track Crash reports of multiple devices with **Different
  PlayStore Id**, and
- provide the database to multiple users.